# Parsing Filename into variables in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have 141 files all with the same format. Below are the first five for reference.

```
400km_t150317_054000
400km_t150317_054100
400km_t150317_054200
400km_t150317_054300
400km_t150317_054400
```

Is there a way in Python to create a loop to take the last portion of the filename and save it in a time array? The 054000, 054100, 054200, 054300, 054400 are all UT times and I can't figure out how to have Python pull this portion of the filename out into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Split the filename

Split the filename at underscores (`_`)

### 2. Convert string to time object

Use `time.strptime(time_string, "%H%M%S")`

### 3. Append new time to time array

Define a `time_array` and append using `time_array.append(time_obj)`

### FINAL CODE

```py
import time

filenames = ['400km_t150317_054000', '400km_t150317_054100', '400km_t150317_054200', '400km_t150317_054300', '400km_t150317_054400']

time_array = []
for f in filenames:
    parts = f.split('_')
    time_string = parts[-1]
    time_obj = time.strptime(time_string, "%H%M%S")
    time_array.append(time_obj)
```

Or concisely, as a list comprehension

```py
import time

filenames = ['400km_t150317_054000', '400km_t150317_054100', '400km_t150317_054200', '400km_t150317_054300', '400km_t150317_054400']

time_array = [time.strptime(f.split('_')[-1], "%H%M%S") for f in filenames]
```

**NOTES**:

- This answer returns a list of time [objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.struct_time), not time strings.
  This behaviour may be desirable if, say, some additional processing has to be done.
- This answer assumes that the time format is `"%H%M%S"` that is, the first 2 digits represent the hour, the next 2, minutes, and the last 2, seconds

**EDIT**: In response to the OP's comment, here is a solution to generate `filenames` array from all the files in the folder and removing the `.dat` or any other extension

```py
import os
import pathlib

filenames = [pathlib.Path(f).stem for f in os.listdir('path/to/folder')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I remove the .dat when I have all 141 filenames to get your code to work? I currently have ```filenames = os.listdir('Folder')``` to get all 141 files into the filenames array, but I'm getting an error when running your code because it still has .dat at the end of 054000.dat, 054100.dat, etc.

Comment: @Sjcarlso, I updated my answer with a solution. Please see.

Answer (score 2):

Using split you can get the time from the file name see the following stuff

```
 filename=["400km_t150317_054000", 
"400km_t150317_054100", 
"400km_t150317_054200", 
"400km_t150317_054300", 
"400km_t150317_054400"]
  
time_array=[]                                                                                                                                
for name in filename: 
   time_array.append(name.split('_')[-1])
```

You can get time. which is last in the filename like

```
 ['054000', '054100', '054200', '054300', '054400']
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get all 141 files that I have into one filename as you have listed above for the first 5? Or would I need to input them all manually?

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```py
filenames = ['400km_t150317_054000', '400km_t150317_054100', '400km_t150317_054200',
             '400km_t150317_054300', '400km_t150317_054400']
output = [x.split('_')[-1] for x in filenames]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['054000', '054100', '054200', '054300', '054400']
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get all 141 files that I have into filenames as you have listed above for the first 5? Or would I need to input them all manually?

Comment: What is the source of your list of filenames?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but all the files are saved in a folder on my computer.

Comment: @Sjcarlso Use `filenames = os.listdir("your_folder_here")`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! What is os.listdir? I don't have that library defined, so it's not recognizing it.